# getopt method in python is not working for large number of arguments

Tags: python

```
import getopt
import sys

options, remainder = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h', ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh'])

list=[]  
for opt, arg in options:
   if opt == '-a':
     list.append(arg.strip())
   if opt == '-b':
     list.append(arg.strip())
   if opt == '-c':
     list.append(arg.strip())
   if opt == '-d':
     list.append(arg.strip())
   if opt == '-e':
     list.append(arg.strip())
   if opt == '-f':
     list.append(arg.strip())
   if opt == '-g':
     list.append(arg.strip())
   if opt == '-h':
     list.append(arg.strip())
print(list)
```

For above code when I give command line arguments:

```
python mainFile.py -a aa -b bb -c cc -d dd -e ee -f ff -g gg -h hh
```

output:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg','']
```

whereas I want :

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh']
```

What should I do to get the desired output.

Comment: You didn't handle `if opt in ('-h')`

Comment: `opt in ('-a')` is the wrong operation. Use `opt == '-a'`.

Comment: sorry. but after adding '-h' handling list is showing extra empty element.

Comment: @MoBaShiR, what do you mean by empty element? Can you elaborate and update the question

Comment: @MoBaShiR, Daniel already provided the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have options with parameters, you have to add `:`, so use `h:` instead of `h`:

```
import getopt
import sys

options, remainder = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:', ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh'])

list=[]  
for opt, arg in options:    
    if opt == '-a':  
        list.append(arg.strip())  
    if opt == '-b':  
        list.append(arg.strip())  
    if opt == '-c':  
        list.append(arg.strip())  
    if opt == '-d':  
        list.append(arg.strip())  
    if opt == '-e':  
        list.append(arg.strip())  
    if opt == '-f':  
        list.append(arg.strip())  
    if opt == '-g':  
        list.append(arg.strip())  
    if opt == '-h':  
        list.append(arg.strip())
print(list)
```

`in` is wrong here, use `==`. And better use a more advanced command line parser, like `argparse`.

Comment: now list output is coming as ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', '']
whereas I want ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh'].Please guide where I am doing mistake now.

Comment: one more small query in getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:', ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff','gg','hh']) what is = used for i.e if we replace it with getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'a:b:c:d:e:f:g:h:', ['aa=','bb=','cc=','dd=','ee=','ff=','gg=','hh='])